# Censoring the given word in a text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python. This is a challenge that I've found in a forum.
This program is censoring the words' (which has given by the user) letters with "*" except the first letter.
For example, If the sentence is "Every breath you take every move you make" and the input word is "every", the output should look like this:

```
2 incidents found.
Censored lyrics:
E**** breath you take e**** move you make
```

This was my only idea but it did not work.

```
text=input("Enter your text: ").lower()
word=input("Choose a word from the previously entered text: ").lower()
def censor(text,word):
t=text.split()
n=[]
for i in t:
    if(i==word):
        n.append("*"*len(word))
    else:
        n.append(i)
return " ".join(n)
print (censor)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `but it did not work` please clarify.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes.

1. In Python 3 you have to use () while printing e.g. print("Hello world") NOT: print "Hello world"
2. `i.lower()==word` because `"Every" != "every"`
3. `n.append(i[0]+"*"*(len(word)-1))` because you want first letter to stay

Code:

```
text=input("Enter your text: ").lower()
word=input("Choose a word from the previously entered text: ").lower()
def censor(text,word):
    t=text.split()
    n=[]
    for i in t:
        if(i.lower()==word):
            n.append(i[0]+"*"*(len(word)-1))
        else:
            n.append(i)
    return " ".join(n)
print(censor(text,word))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an approach related to Regex which could suit this purpose, just consider this as something you can expand on thinking to create your final program:

```
import re

blacklist = ['every']

def replace(match):
    word = match.group()
    if word.lower() in blacklist:
        return word[0]+"*"*(len(word)-1)
    else:
        return word

text = 'Every breath you take every move you make'

text = re.sub(r'\b\w*\b', replace, text, flags=re.I|re.U)
print(text)
```

The advantage this has is that it will work with all kinds of word boundaries that regex recognizes.

You can check the output image below:

[image: Output Image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when you find the word, you just put * you never add the first letter. To fix that you would need:

```
n.append(word[0]+"*"*(len(word)-1))
```

instead of

```
n.append("*"*len(word))
```

Now it will add the first letter and the right number of * afterward.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how it "doesn't work"; when I run your code this is the output:

```
***** breath you take ***** move you make
```

We can tweak your script to leave in the first letter:

```
if(i==word):
    n.append(i[0] + "*"*(len(word)-1))
```

Giving the output as:

```
e**** breath you take e**** move you make
```

Again, it's not actually clear what wasn't working, but that's how you'd show the first letter of each censored word.

Comment: It is really strange that we got different outputs. After choosing the word, my output is <function censor at 0x0000019F782974C0>. @RandomDavis

Comment: @Canan oh are you running Python 2 still?